# File was not found after nuget restore

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and pull the source code from TFS server, then build the solution, I got the following error:

> Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (3863,5): Error MSB3113: The
>   file "SqlServerTypes \ x64 \ SqlServerSpatial140.dll" was not found.

Then I found this dll file comes from the nuget package sqlserver.types, as I know, Visual Studio will restore the nuget packages when we build the solution.

Why I still have this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> File was not found after nuget restore

When you download the nuget package `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` from the [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/) and open it with nuget package explorer:

[image]

You will find the `sqlserver.types` nuget package not only includes `.dll` from .net framework, but also has native binaries files. These files are designed with x64 and x84, they could not added to lib folder directly. So the package owner adds them to project as content. However, these dll files is setting to ignore by default for TFS, you need to add them manually.

Of course, you can also use the command line `Update-Package <package_name> –reinstall` to reinstall this nuget package, but this requires you to execute this command every time after you pull the code from the TFS server. Add this native binaries to the source control will Will reduce these unnecessary troubles.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Update-Package <package_name> –reinstall
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, it works fine, but just like Leo said, "this requires you to execute this command every time after you pull the code from the TFS server", so I add those dll file into the source control. I want to vote up you, but I  do not have enough reputation. But still thank you for you help.